# Problems with like and send buttons on ie7 and ipad

Tags: ipad, button, internet-explorer-7, facebook-like, send

I'm French web developer, i have 2 bugs to fix for my website, i hope you can help...
I have like button, send button, and comment on my website.

The two problems are :

1. in IE7 the facebook like ans send buttons are not displayed correctly, it's buttons of 15px width.
2. On IPad, when I click on the button, the button disappears.

I tried all the codes you propose but nothing is working.

Thank you for your attention and help,

Comment: what code is proposed/tried. There is not enough information here.

Comment: The code use is :<!-- Facebook -->


<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Fin Facebook --> Just after the body tag And in the page : <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.samh-photographie.com" data-font="arial" ></div> Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The given example code works for me. As long as you add // becore connect.facebook

Test page:
http://jsbin.com/igikap/1/edit

Result in IE7:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120920_11_JAR/

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe my like and send buttons are not displayed correctly because I see them in the generator of ie7 in ie9. I have tried your code on my ipad, and the button display correctly but still disappear on click. Could you help me for this point please ? Thank you.